# Jmeter is not able to run as a background process while ssh

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I wrote a shell script , inside shell script I do ssh to jmeter master and execute jmeter command in background using nohup and "&" . Its throwing error : 
An error occurred: Unknown arg: &

ssh $masterIP << EOF
nohup jmeter -n -t $JMETERWS/jmx/$jmxfilename -R $slavePrivateIP -GDISCOVERYURL=$domain -GREGION=$region -GDISCOVERYENV=$env -GSERVICE=$service -GRUNID=$runId -GTESTID=$testId -Gnumthread=$numthread -Gtime=$rampuptime -GSESSIONTIME=$sessiontime  \&
EOF

Comment: try surronding with double quotes "jmeter ..." &

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to your escaping of &:

> \&

Try dropping the escape

Comment: Remove escaping wont work , inside ssh it needs escape character for &

Comment: the problem is & is taking as a argument while running jmeter